# Cross sub domain issue

Tags: ajax, json, cross-domain

I am trying to send ajax call from domain: cdn.foo.com to a service on www.foo.com.

On www.foo.com there is a jsonService.

when I send this :

```
$.ajax({                
    url: json_url + "jsonService/AnyService/someMethod",
    type: "POST",  
    dataType: "json",  
    contentType: "json"
//do something
});
```

I get request but no response.

And when trying to send this :

```
$.ajax({                
    url: json_url + "jsonService/AnyService/someMethod",
    type: "POST",  
    dataType: "jsonp",  
    contentType: "json"
//do something
});
```

I get an error: `405 Method Not Allowed`

I am using tomcat 7.0.12.

what should I do so the request will get to the service?

Comment: solved it by $.post(url , data);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by $.post(url , data);

Answer (score 0):

use jquery's getJSON method:

```
var url = http://www.foo.com/jsonService/AnyService/someMethod?callback=?
$.getJSON(url, function() {...});
```

see the below for a more indepth explanation of jsonp

http://www.devproconnections.com/article/aspnet2/ajax-cross-domain-142169

Comment: still getting 405 not allowed

Comment: are you still trying to POST data? can you send it via GET instead?